# Changing cache_dir and log_dir with Symfony2

Tags: caching, logging, symfony, configuration

Because of deployment constraints, I would like to have the log and cache directories used by my Symfony2 application somewhere under /var/... in my file system. For this reason, I am looking for a way to configure Symfony and to override the default location for these two directories.

I have seen the kernel.cache_dir and kernel.log_dir and read the class Kernel.php. From what I have seen, I don't think that it is possible to change the dir locations by configuration and I would have to patch the Kernel.php class.

Is that true, or is there a way to achieve what I want without modifying the framework code?

Answer (score 20):

Add the following methods to app/AppKernel.php (AppKernel extends Kernel) making them return your preferred paths:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->rootDir . '/my_cache/' . $this->environment;
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return $this->rootDir . '/my_logs';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I was happy to find your post, but I was a little bit confused of the unhelping answers.

I got the same problem and found out that the logs are depending on the config parameter 
`kernel.logs_dir`.

So I just added it to my `config.yml` parameters:

```
kernel.logs_dir: /var/log/symfonyLogs
```

I hope it will helpfull for you even, if its a late answer.

Answer (score 6):

i think the easiest way is to link the folder to another place. We have made this on the prod server but when you develop local perhaps on windows its a bit complicated to set the symlinks.

```
ln -s /var/cache/ /var/www/project/app/cache
```

something like this.

Comment: I have solved lots of problems (like the stupid bugs in Assetic) very easily with `ln -snf`, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to offer an alternative and that is to set environment variables to change these directories. This way it's easier to set depending on the stage. (testing, production or development)

```
export SYMFONY__KERNEL__CACHE_DIR "/your/directory/cache"
export SYMFONY__KERNEL__LOGS_DIR "/your/directory/logs"
```

Environment variables can also be set in the virtual host with SetEnv.
When reading kernel parameters symfony will look for all the $_SERVER variables that start with SYMFONY__, strip the first part and convert all the double underscores into a .

[Source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L568)

See line 568 to 608

Comment: This is [deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L642) since version 3.3

Answer (score 1):

In symfony you can override the cache (and logs) directory by extending the method in AppKernel.

```
// app/appKernel.php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return $this->rootDir.'/'.$this->environment.'/cache';
    }
}
```

Check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-cache-dir

Answer (score 0):

I used the [configuration solution from Dragnic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745808/2257664) but I put the paths in the `parameters.yml` file because this file is ignored by git. in other words, it's not synchronized from my PC to the git repository so there is no impact in the `prod` environment.

```yaml
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    [...]
    kernel.cache_dir: "T:/project/cache"
    kernel.logs_dir: "T:/project/logs"
```

Configuration: Windows7, WAMP 2.4 and Symfony 2.3.20.

But you have to know that:

> Overwriting the `kernel.cache_dir` parameter from your config file is a very bad idea, and not a supported way to change the cache folder in Symfony.
>
> It breaks things because you would now have different cache folders for the kernel `Kernel::getCacheDir()` and for the parameter.

Source: https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/370

So you should use it only in `dev` environment and if you don't want to change the content of the <kbd>app/AppKernel.php</kbd> file, otherwise see the other answers.

Comment: WARNING => BAD IDEA!!! especially if you're using Assetic: https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/370

Comment: @Oliboy50: thanks, I updated my answer in order to warn users.

Answer (score 0):

No accepted answer, and a really old question, but I found it with google, so I post here a more recent way to change the cache directory, and the logs directory, ([source here](https://beberlei.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html))

- [remember, short syntax for arrays require php 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)
- you can select the env to modify, and manage different cache and logs directories if you want

  ```
  public function getCacheDir()
  {
      if (in_array($this->environment, ['prod', 'test'])) {
      return '/tmp/cache/' .  $this->environment;
  }

  return parent::getCacheDir();
  }

  public function getLogDir()
  {
      if (in_array($this->environment, ['prod', 'test'])) {
      return '/var/log/symfony/logs';
  }

  return parent::getLogDir();
  }
  ```