# Symfony2: Same codebase with multiple environments leads to tons of cache files

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, caching, doctrine

I have a running **Symfony2** application which uses the same codebase, but different environment names to map to different DBs.

For example:

**foo**.example.com --> uses env **foo**
**bar**.example.com --> uses env **bar**

Of course, I have now different **cache** and **logs** for each user.

The cache thing is what bothers me, it's creating tons of files (1 cache dir per subdomain), and it ended up filling my inodes to the limit.

Is there a way to share the cache between environments, or maybe not using **environments** to access different dbs?

Each **subdomain** should have its own **DB**, that's the only requirements. Right now we are using different environments to accomplish that.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that an environment has a lot of cache files. The problem is that the idea of environment is exploited the wrong way.

A better solution for your situation is to define your db name based on the subdomain: foo.example.com will have the db foo_db, etc. A simple convention like that.

Answer (score -1):

This answer may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314039/410761

You override the base methods to define whatever cache / logs folder you prefer.